# How to Solve this ODE with Mixed Boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have an ODE equation which is sort of

```
y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + .0001 (y[x])^3 ==0
```

subject to the boundary conditions

```
y'[0]==0  and y[Infinity]==0
```

Can anyone please suggest what would be a reliable process for solving this numerically in Mathematica?

`y[Infinity]` can obviously be truncated down to , say, `y[20]`.

Comment: Check the `NDSolve` docs and examples!

Comment: The examples do not address the situation that  at x=0 the y'[x]/x term is undefined.

Comment: I see what is the difficulty now.  Please, next time indicate the problem clearly in the question.  Lately there have been several questions where the OP clearly hasn't even looked at the docs.  On first read yours sounds like "how do I solve a diff eq numerically", so people will dismiss it without even looking at the ODE.

Comment: `y[x] == 0` is a solution to your differential equation.

Comment: Yes it is - but I am pretty certain that there are other non-trivial solutions

Comment: Umm - no takers on this on! Bump! Is this allowed here? If not my sincere apologies and mods please delete this post.

Comment: A comment won't bump it up.  To have a better chance of getting an answer: edit your post, explain why you can't just pass the ode to NDSolve, and explain why you think that there are other solutions than $y=0$.  Without these explanations, on a first skim the post looks like you didn't take the time to look up how to use NDSolve, so people won't come back to it.  An edit *will* bump it back to the front page, but please don't do it only for the bump: make sure you include this information.

Comment: @Szabolcs brings up a good point.  If $y(\infty) = 0$, and $y$ has continuous end behavior, then shouldn't $y'(\infty) = 0$? Trying the following: `NDSolve[{ y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + .0001 (y[x])^3 == 0, y[20] == 0, 
  y'[20] == 0}, y, {x, 2, 20}]` results in a trivial solution.

Comment: y[Inf]-> 0 does not imply y'[Inf]->0, witness y=Sin[x^2]/x ..

Answer (score 2):

The comments by @george2079 are spot on IMO regarding the asymptotic behaviour at infinity and also that the way to solve this is by formulating it as a Cauchy problem. I don't see an issue with replacing zero with $ \epsilon $ however. In any case, changing the boundary value at infinity with a boundary value at "zero" (that is to be tweaked) works:

```
sol = Table[
  First@NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + .0001 (y[x])^3 == 0, 
     y'[10^(-10)] == 0, y[10^(-10)] == a}, 
    y, {x, 10^(-10), 1000}], {a, -5, 5, .5}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: asymptotic]

i.e. any $ y(0) = a \in \mathbb{R} $ seems to give a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $ y(\infty)=0$, and $ y $ has continuous end behaviour, then shouldn't $ y'(\infty)=0 $? Trying the following:

```
NDSolve[{ y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x + .0001 (y[x])^3 == 0, y'[10^(-10)] == 0, y[20] == 0}, y, {x, 10^(-10), 20}]
```

results in the trivial solution $ y(x) = 0. $ Can you explain why you think that there are other solutions than the trivial one?

Comment: similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482835/finding-out-the-nodes-from-spherical-symmetric-equation-for-mathematica-and-then#comment1043755_482835, and I'll say quite annoying to have to resort the y'[eps] hack.. bc.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I didn't pay any attention when I posted the community wiki from the comments but this is much easier to solve than the one you link to.